# How can I use other published module functions in my move module?

Tags: move-lang, diem

I need to call some other module functions (Those already published modules in aptos blockchain) in my move module.

1. How can I import those module functions in my module?
2. How to add that module as a dependency in my Move.toml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies section of your Move.toml allows you to specify packages, such as the Sui package, which needs a pointer to the correct github repository and branch:

```
[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
```

And then you would import that package and module into your module like so:

```
module my_package::my_module {
    use sui::object::{Self, ID, UID};
}
```

Where `sui` is the imported package, object is the imported `module`, `ID`, and `UID` are structs in the module, and `Self` allows you to reference the module functions (e.g. `object::new()`)

Comment: Consider extending your answer, specifically in the manifest file, to demonstrate linking to a local directory as well.